# Нужна ли запятая в конструкциях с "Что если"?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после *что* в предложениях:

Что если это очередной развод?
Что если у меня не получится?

Answer (score 6):

Нужна, [похоже](http://punktuaciya.academic.ru/731/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE(,)_%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8_(%D0%B1%D1%8B)).

В таких вопросах опущено сказуемое:

> Что [*будет*]**,** если это очередной развод?
>    Что [*случится*]**,** если у меня не получится?

Так что ставьте.

Answer (score 6):

(А) ЧТО, ЕСЛИ (БЫ) - частица в вопросительном предложении в роли междометия. Выражает опасение (то же, что «а вдруг», «а ну как»), а также употребляется при обращении с нерешительной просьбой. Перед «если» обычно ставится запятая.
«Что, если она сама не знает того, что делает?» – спрашивал он себя. Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина. Что, если бы я не бросил ее? И. Бунин, Темные аллеи.

В художественной литературе встречаются примеры непостановки запятой перед словом «если»: Что если кто-нибудь заметит его посреди реки? В. Бианки, Лесные были и небылицы. А что если нам еще раз голубую змейку позвать? П. Бажов, Голубая змейка. Но это можно отнести к авторской пунктуации.

Не смешивать со стыком союзов «что» и «если (бы)» в сложноподчиненном предложении. Запятая на стыке союзов не ставится, если второй союз имеет в главной части предложения соотносительное слово «то». При отсутствии соотносительного слова «то» запятая на стыке союзов ставится.
Я шучу, конечно, но всё же... странно, и я убежден, что если бы вы остались, то опустошение произошло бы громадное. А. Чехов, Дядя Ваня. Очень вероятно, что, если бы им представилась возможность вернуться к прежней мирной жизни, оба они, и Анна и Корецкий, схватились бы за эту возможность. В. Брюсов, Через пятнадцать лет.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_759